# when i am updating 12.04 to 13.10 then following error show

Tags: 12.04

```
E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/
archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_quantal-updates_main_i18n_Translation-en (1), 
E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

This error show what I'm doing to solve this error?

Comment: You can not directly upgrade from 12.04 to 13.10

Answer (score 0):

First remove following files by opening a terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch) and run this command:

```
sudo rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Next, generate a new one by running a simple update:

```
sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get update
```